# usage of options in R

Tags: r

I read the following code from the internet,

```
mem <- options(warn=2)
# ... some operations ...
options(mem)
```

I check the document of `options`, the `options(warn=2)` returns a list on the setting of warning display. But I don't understand the function of `options(mem)`, I think it's the same thing as `options(warn=2)`, am I wrong?

Comment: `options(warn = 2)` returns the previous value, so `options(mem)` restores it.

Comment: I found the reason, thank you@user2554330